# Как сделать переход с UICollectionView на UIViewCntroller с передачей значений?

Tags: xcode, swift, uicollectionview

Идея состоит в том, чтобы при тапе на иконку открывалась новая страница с информацией, соответствующей иконке. 
При выборе CollectionViewCell и переходе на новый контроллер всегда отображает начальный элемент массива, на котором и построена вся CollectionView. При дальнейшем выборе ячеек отображает предыдущую, а не фактически выбранную. Почему так происходит, не понимаю.

P.S. Если есть более простой способ передачи информации о нажатой ячейке в новую вьюху, буду признателен.

**Метод сохранения и присвоения значения в новый UIViewController:**

```
    var name : AnyObject? {
    get {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("name")
    }
    set {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue, forKey: "name")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let testView : SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
    testView.testString = name as! String
    print(testView.testString)
}
```

**Реализация CollectionView:**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return heroArray.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : myvwCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myvwCell

    cell.lblCell.text = heroArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: heroArray[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("pressed \(heroArray[indexPath.row])")


    name = heroArray[indexPath.row]

}
```

**Реализация SecondViewController:**

```
import UIKit


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imgFullView: UIImageView!
 var testString = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imgFullView.image = UIImage(named: testString)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

Comment: Вы сохраняете данные в `name` и хотите их отобразить в `SecondViewController`?

Comment: На данном этапе - да. Можно еще в SecondViewController добавить гетер name (видел в одном примере), тогда функция prepareForSegue  в принципе не нужна. при этом результат не меняется, я все так же наблюдаю эту странную ошибку.

Comment: Вообще, если есть метод, как мне перенести данные с одного контроллера в другой и который будет работать корректно, то я буду рад его изучить.

Comment: @Zarochintsev у вас есть предположение, что может быть не так в моем коде?

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо добавить функцию обработки перед seque:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aboutHero", sender: self)
```

После чего уже прописать функцию самого seque:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "aboutHero" {
        let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! HeroViewController
        vc.imageHero = UIImage(named: self.heroArray[indexPath.row].name)!         
    }
```

Код от исходного слегка отличается названием переменных, но суть ясна.

Answer (score 0):

Создал для вас тестовый проект [тут](https://github.com/zarochintsev/Demo). Посмотрите, если что-то будет не понятно - пишите.